# Maven -U option update NON-SNAPSHOT release

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have 2 questions about the -U option,

1- I saw alot of questions and articles that say the -U option only updates the snapshot. However from the documentation of Maven 3.0.1 :

```
Forces a check for updated releases and snapshots on remote repositories
```

so does this mean in latest Maven it will check for updated NON-SNAPSHOT dependency ?

2- let's say I have a dependency on a local project that doesn't exist in the remote repository, what will be the behavior of -U option? the jar won't be on remote repository so it can't compare it , the project is not on the remote repo.